# Coloured Screen Overlays for Visual Stress

Tags: 19.04

I am hoping you guys can help me.  I am fairly new to using Linux as my daily driver and am working on a project to compile ways of making different operating systems more user friendly for people with learning difficulties such as dyslexia.  The customisation in Linux is great for this, however I have hit one area where I can't find a solution.

Is there away to tint a whole screen so that any application that opens doesn't have a plain white background and black text.  Ideally something that could be applied system wide and switched on and off with relative ease?  This is the sort of thing that I mean but for windows.
https://www.aurelitec.com/colorveil/windows/

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Search the site for *redshift*. That may help.

Comment: Alternatively, you could find themes to change the foreground & background of windows.

Comment: @Peter Winkley You may also find this helpful: https://opendyslexic.org/